# Google Map API V3 Polygon DragEnd Event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are trying to add a dragend event to a polygon so that when the user release the mouse, something happens. However, the dragend on the polygon seems to fire like drag. i.e. fires continously and not just once when the dragging has finished.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'dragend', function () {
       // Do something just once when dragging has ended.
    });
```

Anyone come across this issue. Is this a bug?
Many thanks.

Comment: The dragend event on a polygon works as I expect ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/evvwwfrj/2/)).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @user2981411 Thanks for your reply. What you are doing is just getting the end position and show it. This does not mean the event has not fired several times before getting there. To see this behaviour try and store the path in an array for example event.overlay.addListener('dragend', function () {
             array.unshift(  google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(this.getPath()));
          } and you will see that the array will contain many elements and not just the last position.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: @user2981411 I just did : event.overlay.addListener('dragend', function () { array.unshift( google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(this.getPath())); }

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the event listener like this:

```
overlay.addListener('dragend', function () {
  console.log('Drag end!');
});
```

Take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/moonflare/a0gmf6y9/5/) example. It might work this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To see this behaviour try and store the path in an array for example event.overlay.addListener('dragend', function () {
             array.unshift(  google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(this.getPath()));
          } and you will see that the array will contain many elements and not just the last position.